# Tap for washing machine only works at low pressures

Tags: taps

My washing machine is connected to a dedicated tiny wall tap (whose wall is in fact an empty space which can be accessed), which in turn is connected via a flexible internal pipe to a divider, and then to the main valve which serve the whole bathroom.

Recently, the pressure have been lower, and even more recently, the flow stopped completely.
All the other faucets are working fine.

The most weird thing, is that if I reduce the maximum flow a lot (to around 0.07 l/s) from the main valve, then it works. Any little amount of pressure more, and it stops.
Note that it has hysteresis: I need to relieve the pressure almost completely for it to resume.

This is true even when the washing machine is disconnected and there is nothing after the tap.

What could make a tap work in a so bizarre way?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Does the flow stop completely? Have you tried disconnecting the flexible pipe from the tap to see if the blockage is before the tap?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a screen fitting at the faucet, lots of small particles of rust or scale plugging the screen a tiny flow and there is not enough pressure to plug all the holes open the flow up and the holes get plugged. I would check for a screen at the valve these can be cleaned off as they are usually brass and won’t corrode. If it is in good shape after cleaning off put it back in these screens keep the small chunks out of the machines solenoid valves, 1 small chunk can hold a solenoid valve slightly open and next time you check you have a flood without the screen at a later time,  so clean it and put it back in if damaged a new pair is only a couple of dollars.